# Melhor forma de gerar Holerite, procuro uma solução mais viável

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, dbase

Desenvolvi uma aplicação que gera Holerites, e para tal preciso tratar dados vindos de 4 tabelas.

> Funcionarios -> Empresas -> Vencimentos -> Descontos

Quero mostrar ao meu usuário da seguinte forma por exemplo:

> Rafael trabalha na empresa X e tem 10 vencimentos e 20 Descontos.

Exemplo de Código:

```
$total_vencimento= 0;
$total_desconto = 0;

// Aqui em funcionários realizei um join com empresas.
foreach ($funcionarios as $funcionario) {

  foreach ($vencimentos as $vencimento) {
    //VERIFICA SE PERTENCE AO FUNCIONARIO ATUAL E PRINTA
    $total_vencimento += $vencimento->valor;
  }

  foreach ($descontos as $desconto) {
    //VERIFICA SE PERTENCE AO FUNCIONARIO ATUAL E PRINTA
    $total_desconto += $desconto->valor;
  }

  // Aqui apresentaria o valor liquido entra Vencimentos - Descontos

}
```

Imagem de exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de realizar uma query ou procedimento pelo PHP mesmo, para poder gerar esses Holerites. Vou gerar os Holerites baseado no ID da empresa. O usuário vai selecionar a empresa e vai gerar os Holerites de todos os funcionários, descriminando os nomes dos Vencimentos e Descontos e seus valores.

Atualmente estou trazendo todos os funcionários pertencentes a empresa, e seus respectivos vencimentos e descontos. Rodo tudo isso em um foreach e checo se aquele vencimento/desconto pertence a o funcionário atual do loop e printo.

Comment: Qual estrutura da de suas tabelas? Você pode utilizar [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: O Join traria todos os registros de vencimentos e descontos ? Ele não traz só um ?

Comment: Utilize `Left Join`. Ele irá trazer vários resultados. A depender do que você queira, nem é preciso fazer um `foreach`, basta somar tudo com uma `query sql`.

Comment: Adicionei uma foto de como eu quero mostrar, quero mostrar o funcionário, a empresa que ele trabalha e descriminar cada vencimento e desconto.

Answer (score 1):

Se utilizar o relacionamento através da Model você consegue esse resultado apenas com uma linha.

Para isso precisa ter feito o relacionamento entre as tabelas através da criação de chaves estrangeiras no momento da criação das tabelas via migration, se não fez não tem problema, basta criar manualmente o relacionamento através do editor SQL que você usa.

Depois entra nas Models e cria o relacionamento, **exemplo**:

**Na Model "Funcionarios"**

```
public function descontos(){

    return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Desconto");
}
```

**Na Model Descontos**

```
public function funcionarios(){

    return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Funcionarios");
}
```

Depois você pode extrair os dados com algo como:

```
$result = Funcionarios::has('descontos')->get();
```

Espero ter ajudado, pode dar uma olhada também na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: Vou fazer uns testes, meu banco já está configurado seguindo o modelo do Eloquent. O maior problema que eu vejo é o seguinte, como na imagem de exemplo eu estou gerando um PDF que contem as informações dos funcionários e todos os seus créditos e descontos discriminando valor e o nome. Tentei realizando um inner join mas apenas traz 1 resultado de cada e não todos. Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de trazer do banco cada funcionário mostrando sua empresa e discriminando seus créditos e descontos.